# Access RDS from Lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, amazon-rds

I have an Aurora cluster in RDS and a Lambda Function.

- Both are assigned the same VPC.
- Both have the same subnets (us-east-1 a-f)
- Both have the same security group assigned
- Lambda is assigned a role with AmazonRDSFullAccess, AmazonVPCFullAccess, 
  AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole

When I run the lambda instance, I get connection timeout when trying to connect to Aurora.  I'm able to access Aurora locally (with access key added to aws configure).

Any ideas what else I can check for why lambda wouldn't have access to the instance? Thank you

Update: The subnets each have the following configuration:
[image]
[image: route table]

Comment: What are the security group rules? You probably need to open the port.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Both have the same security group assigned

It's a common misconception that members of the same security group can communicate with each other by virtue of being members of the same group.  This is not the case. Being members of the same group only means they follow the same set of rules.

Members of a security group can only access other members of the group if the group allows access to itself.

> Instances associated with a security group can't talk to each other unless you add rules allowing it (exception: the default security group has these rules by default).
>
> http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_SecurityGroups.html

Add a rule to this group for "MySQL/Aurora" traffic, but instead of entering an IP address, enter the `sg-xxxxxxxx` identifier of the security group.

Comment: I actually ended up adding in the VPC cidr block as the source in the security group for 3306.   But this answer is exactly where I was running into problems.

Comment: It's good to know that you got it working.  Added a little snippet from the docs, re: "instances" (which may not aways be what you think of as "instances") in the same group.   You should probably consider splitting this up into two security groups and using the sg-xxxxxxx of the source group (Lambda group) in a rule in the target group (RDS group), as a matter of best practice.  You do not need a rule in the opposite direction (Lambda group needs no rule, since connections are not initiated inward, towards the actual Lambda containers, only outward from them).

Comment: That makes sense, using two two security groups.   I'll update that, Thanks again!

Comment: If anybody can't figure out why they're getting the 'Task timed out after...' message when testing a Lambda function calling out to RDS, despite having the VPCAccess and Basic execution roles for Lambda, and specifying the RDS security group under 'Network' for that function, this may be the cause. It seems somewhat counter-intuitive, but go to the Security Group's settings, and add a rule for that group itself to the Inbound Rules, as specified above. So give that group access to RDS, via the group's own Inbound Rules settings.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem until I realized the VPC I was using did not have dns resolution enabled for hosts within the VPC.

The enableDnsSupport option needs to be set for the VPC.

See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/vpc-dns.html

Comment: Thanks - I have DNS resolution enabled though.

Comment: @dzm - ok - thanks for updating - sounds like it might be your network then - subnets - lambda can only see the private subnet. You didn't mention your NAT/Gateway setup or what the route table looks like, private or public.

Comment: thank you.  So I updated with two screenshots for what each subnet has.  I'm not sure if this info is sufficient?

Comment: @dzm - looks like those are public and it looks like you are missing a NAT - you need the NAT for the private subnet. see http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/vpc.html

Comment: Thanks @abdollar, so it looks like I'd need to create a NAT Gateway for each subnet? us-east-1 A-F? If I'm going to have my lambda and RDS assigned to all available subnets?

Comment: You dont need a NAT to access something inside the VPC. You only need a NAT to access resources outside the VPC.

Comment: @MarkB for lambda it looks like you cannot have both internet and local VPC access with a lambda unless you have a NAT - see http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/vpc.html - unless I am reading it wrong

Comment: Ok, I found the issue.  My security group had 3306 open only to my own IP (I did this when I originally set it up - a while ago and completely forgot), I've added in an additional inbound for 3306 with the VPC CIDR block as the source and it's working now.  Thanks for all your suggestions.

Comment: @abdollar you are correct that you can't have both Internet and VPC access in a Lambda function without a NAT gateway. However this question is about accessing VPC resources only, not Internet resources. You don't need a NAT Gateway if you only need to access VPC resources.